# 1D Data for NLP models

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, transformer

My dataset( Network traffic dataset where we do binary classification)-

[image]

Number of features in data is 25

Can we use this kind of dataset in NLP models like transformers? If yes what should be the transformations to be done on this to feed it into models like transformers for binary classification?

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to use NLP methods with structured numerical data: do you want to merge all the features as if it's a text sequence? I might be missing something but this doesn't feel like a good idea to me.

Comment: @Erwan yes I want to merge the features as if its a text sequence

Comment: I might be missing something but let me explain why I don't think that's a good idea: text is unstructured data, i.e. by itself it doesn't have any clear structure where the first word has a specific role, the 2nd word as well, etc. But also text is sequential, i.e. the order of the words matters to represent the meaning of the sentence. Your data is structured, i.e. each feature has a specific role, and the features are not sequential, i.e. there's no particular reason why the mean is before the std. dev. for instance, it could be the opposite.

Comment: Imho merging the features like a text sequence makes the job of the model much harder, because it has to rediscover the original structure. My guess is that *at best* the model would perform as well as if it was fed the original data, I don't see how it could perform better.